# Javascript function argument in array

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
String.prototype.callcm = function(something[]){
alert(something);
};
```

`"something".callcm({a:50,b:60});`

how can the arguments with there variable name get in the something array.

Comment: As a side note, it's a good idea to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`, as it will allow you to interact with the object in your developer tools console. This might be useful as you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking for a way to pass the values `{a:50,b:60}` to the function.. then you just need to fix the syntax.

Change `function(something[])`

to `function(something)`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/d4UXV/) here